# Porque este codigo no funciona en Qt? creando regla en registro

Tags: c++, qt

Hola estoy creando una regla en el registro usando c++ con QT y la funcion de windows para ello incorporo las siguientes librerias:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

Luego creo la regla usando el siguiente ejemplo:

```
//asignamos key el valor nulo
      HKEY key = 0;
      //elegimos la ruta donde se creara
      LPCTSTR ruta = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
      //con status podemos saber si se creo correctamente
      long status = RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, ruta, &key);
      if (status != 0)
      {
        cout << "Win error: " << GetLastError() <<  endl;
      }
      else
      {
        //cout << "Nombre de la subclave: ";
        string subclave="System";
        //getline(cin, subclave);
        cout << "Valor de la subclave: ";
        string valor="C:\\miprograma.exe";
        //getline(cin, valor);
        LPCTSTR _subclave = TEXT(subclave.c_str());
        LPCTSTR _valor = TEXT(valor.c_str());
        long crear = RegSetValueEx(key, _subclave, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE) _valor, strlen(_valor) * sizeof(char));
        if (crear != 0)
        {
          cout << "Win error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
          cout << "Subclave creada correctamente" << endl;
        }
      }

      RegCloseKey(key);
```

Pero qt me da los siguientes errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es en qt no puede usar iostream o usar el siguiente código? Deberia funcionar no se porque obtengo estos errores ya que incluí las librerias.. Por último, necesito de otra manera diferente a crearlo qsettings para la aplicación que estoy creando que vendrá con esta opción en mi aplicación de escritorio.

errores al usar .c_str:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hola estoy creando una regla en el registro usando c++ con QT

Te corrijo. Estarás usando QtCreator que es el IDE que trae Qt, pero no estás haciendo uso de ninguna función o característica propia de Qt, luego a todos los usos te daría lo mismo compilar desde codeblocks o cualquier otro IDE.

> Mi pregunta es en qt no puede usar iostream o usar el siguiente código?

Qt no es más que un framework para C++, cualquier característica de C++ estará disponible también si trabajas con Qt. Y esto incluye la librería estándar de C++.

Dicho esto, vamos a analizar tus problemas:

```
string subclave="System";
```

En C++ las funciones y clases de la librería estándar están agrupados por espacios de nombres. Para poder llamar a una funcionalidad de la librería estándar es necesario indicar el espacio de nombres correspondiente y esto se puede hacer de tres formas diferentes:

1. Indicar el espacio de nombres en cada uso. La principal ventaja de este sistema es que **siempre** podemos estar seguros de a qué funcionalidad estamos recurriendo.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
     std::string a;
     std::cout << "Introduce un nombre ";
     std::cin >> a;
     std::cout << a;
   }
   ```
2. Importar el espacio de nombres completo. Aunque es lo primero que te suelen enseñar no suele ser el más recomendado

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   // Puede ir antes o después de los includes.
   // Por motivos históricos se suelen poner los includes primero
   using namespace std; 

   int main()
   {
     string a;
     cout << "Introduce un nombre ";
     cin >> a;
     cout << a;
   }
   ```
3. Importar únicamente aquellas funciones o clases que nos interesen. Es un mecanismo más limpio ya que la importación es más selectiva, lo que ayuda a reducir las colisiones

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   using std::cout;
   using std::string;

   int main()
   {
     string a;
     cout << "Introduce un nombre ";
     std::cin >> a; // no se ha importado std::cin
     cout << a;
   }
   ```

Por otro lado, la creación del registro tiene problemas también:

```
long crear = RegSetValueEx(key, _subclave, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE) _valor, strlen(_valor) * sizeof(char));
```

La función `RegSetValueEx` espera que (_valor) sea de tipo LPCTSTR y este tipo es un alias cuyo tipo concreto puede variar:

- `const char*` si no se ha definido `_UNICODE`
- `const wchar*` si se ha definido `_UNICODE`

Así pues no parece buena idea llamar a `strlen` pasándole una variable de tipo `LPCTSTR` ya que habrá casos en los que no compile. Para solucionar este problema existe la macro `_tcslen`:

```
long crear = RegSetValueEx(key, _subclave, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE) _valor, _tcslen(_valor));
```